# File download ignores HTTP_PROXY set in CMakeLists

Tags: curl, cmake, http-proxy

I work behind a proxy and I have to use some 3rd party tools. I cannot assume that proxy is set on every computer that will use this script.
Though proxy is set in the script `file(DOWNLOAD)` and also `ExternalProject_Add` does not work. It work only if the environment variable http_proxy (or HTTP_PROXY on Windows) is set before running this script.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.0)
project(external VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
include(ExternalProject)

set(ENV{HTTP_PROXY}  "myproxyx:8080")

ExternalProject_Add(
  catch-external
  PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Catch
  URL https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/archive/v1.10.0.tar.gz
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(catch-external source_dir)
include_directories(${source_dir}/single_include)

# It also fails:
# file(DOWNLOAD https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/archive/v1.10.0.tar.gz ./catch.tar.gz)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
add_dependencies(main catch-external)
```

Eg. on Windows this works for me (with the proper address of course):
set HTTP_PROXY="http://myproxy:8080" & set HTTPS_PROXY="http://myproxy:8080" & cmake .

The affected cmake version is 3.12.0.

Is there a way to pass proxy address to libcurl in cmake?

Comment: Why do you want to include it in the CMake file? I think it's best to stay with  setting the variable externally, like for all machine-specific stuff. Else, it would require everyone without or with another proxy to change the build script. This implies further problems, like: Which setting goes to version control system?, etc.

Comment: The server is far out of my control and probably won't change in the near future. It seems very convenient to set this constant only once and no one have to worry about configuration. It will be used in a very diverse environments (from any kind of linux distro, docker, different IDEs, Jenkins etc). I was just surprised that cmake allows to set an environment variable, but some part of it simply ignores it.

Comment: Good to see your cmake bug report: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18269

Comment: [Brad King](https://gitlab.kitware.com/brad.king) answered [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18269#note_447087).  "`set(ENV{...} ...)` only affects the environment of the CMake process driving the configuration and generation." Download occurs in a separate environment.